# определение типа DOM элемента

Tags: javascript, функции

```
function setTitleForElement(domElement, someTitle) {

  for (var i = 0; i < domElement.length; i++) {
    if (domElement.nodeName === 'IMG') {
        domElement[i] = domElement[i].setAttribute('alt', someTitle);
        domElement[i] = domElement[i].setAttribute('title', someTitle)
    } else {
       domElement[i] = domElement[i].setAttribute('title', someTitle);
    }
  } 
}
```

есть код, при вводе DOM элемента ему (или им) присваивается атрибут `title`, нужно выделить чтобы когда вводился `img` (`document.querySelectorAll('img')`) присваивалось помимо `title` и `alt`. Ввожу проверку с помощью `nodeName` чтобы выделить `img`, но код не работает. Как еще можно выделить `img` среди других элементов?

Comment: `return domElement[i]`??? - `domElement[domElement.length]`?

Comment: `domElement[i].setAttribute` - no return value

Comment: @Igor, да, return надо удалить. Но на работоспособность он не влияет.

Comment: да, с return не красиво вышло..

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if (domElement.nodeName === 'img') {
> ```

```
if (domElement[i].nodeName === 'IMG') {
```

> ```
> domElement[i] = domElement[i].setAttribute('alt', someTitle);
> domElement[i] = domElement[i].setAttribute('title', someTitle)
> ```

```
domElement[i].alt = someTitle;
domElement[i].title = someTitle;
```

Comment: ошибся при написании на сайте, в коде у меня заглавными, но не работает.

Comment: @Веня, ответ обновлён.

Comment: 'function setTitleForElement(domElement, someTitle) 
{
for (var i = 0; i < domElement.length; i++) {
 if (domElement.nodeName === 'img') {
        domElement[i].alt = someTitle;
        domElement[i].title = someTitle;
} else {
       domElement[i].title = someTitle;
}
} 
}' выходит так, но к сожалению ситуация не решилась (все равно при вводе элемента img выходит else), проблема наверное в запросе if.

Comment: `domElement.nodeName` -> `domElement[i].nodeName`

Comment: @Веня, так у тебя опять буквы маленькие.

Comment: @Igor, да. Поправил ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy это да, снова поспешил когда писал, но дело не в этом. тут проблема была в if (domElement.nodeName === 'IMG') , нужно if (domElement[i].nodeName === 'IMG') было..